# Difference in meaning: past perfect and simple past

Tags: grammar, verbs, tenses, past-tense

She lived in Switzerland for ten years when she was a child.

or

She had lived in Switzerland for ten years when she was a child.

Being a non-native speaker, sometimes i get confused.

Comment: You might find this helpful: [Past Perfect](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/pastperfect.html) and [Past Simple](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/simplepast.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first choice is the correct one.  She was a child for more than ten years, and she lived in Switzerland for ten years within that time frame.

The second is incorrect because you would use past perfect to describe an action that was interrupted by another, later action.

**She had lived in Switzerland for ten years when her parents decided to move the family to Swaziland.**

Here, the second action (moving to Swaziland) took place ten years after she started living in Switzerland.

In your sentence, the phrase **she was a child** does not work that way.

Answer (score 0):

We use the past perfect to talk about the order of events in the past.  Police, lawyers, doctors, and historians use it frequently.  It is common for non native speakers to make pp mistakes because they use the present as a reference point or they use a reference point that is not included in the sentence but which they are thinking of.